# Inherit classpath id in master build.xml

Tags: ant, antbuilder

I have a base build.xml in that contains:

```
<path id="master-classpath-common-lib" >
    <fileset dir="${master.classpath}/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

I want to inherit this path id in all the build.xml as all these dependencies are required for compiling. I tried the below solution, but don't understand how to do it.  Below piece of code should inherit all the id's shouldn't it?

```
<ant antfile="${st.lib}/build.xml" inheritrefs="true"/>
```

when I put

```
id = master-classpath-common-lib
```

in

```
classpathref
```

of `javac` task it does not work.

Why it is not working?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Are you getting `Reference classpath not found` error?

Comment: Yes i am getting reference classpath not found